# Pentagon chipher

Tags: cipher

Please help! Its a swedish scoutcipher.
[image: cipher]

Comment: ...If it's a cipher for you as a Swedish Scout, don't you think you'd benefit much more from doing this yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pentagon suggests

> base 5 (as well as the fact that all of the digits are 0-4)

Next,

> notice that the Swedish alphabet has 29 letters, so things like 104 and 102 etc. make sense. Dots serve as word breaks. Furthermore there is a canonical ordering: the letters A-Z in order, then Å, Ä, and Ö. So we can just translate: **GÖR IORDNING SIMGLASÖGONEN MED TAPE ÖVER LINSEN SÅ DET EJ GÅR ATT SE IGENOM NÄR MAN HAR DEM PÅ SIG KLARTL FEM**. Looks Swedish to me (something something med tape?) but I might've made an error or something. At any rate, I'm sure you're better at this step than I am :P